# How can I create RSS on specific field in my list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, rss

In Microsoft SharePoint 2010
I have a list including 4 items:

- Item Name
- Revision
- Notes
- Type

How can I create RSS notification which include "Item Name" and "Revision" in Subject